# Why use the "Where" clause in method definition

Tags: c#, casting, where-clause

I came across a bit of code today that I'm trying to get my head around and trying to understand the advantages of using "where : class" in the method definition.

Code obviously simplified.

```
    private class Test
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
    }

    private AB Invoke<AB>() where AB : class
    {
        return new Test() as AB;
    }

    private object RunMethod()
    {
        return new Test();
    }
```

Each method is called in the following ways.

```
// Method1
Test ResultTest = Invoke<Test>();

// Method2
Test ResultTest = RunMethod() as Test;
```

Are there any other advantages apart from not having to Cast or use "as".
Also what is this called?

Comment: "what is this called" - it's a constraint on the type parameter - reading up on this might help you understand the advantages: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Try to write `Invoke<int>();` and you will see

Comment: It is just constraints that specify that it would not accept anything except reference types.

Answer (score 2):

[`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) keyword provides as safe cast. If the object cannot be casted a `null` will be returned.

[`where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) on the other hand is a generic type constraint. It will ensure that you will use a correct type when using this generic or your code will not *compile*.

Answer (score 1):

Omitting `where AB : class` will give you the compilation error *"The type parameter 'AB' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint"*.

The `as` operator in `as T` requires `T` to be a reference or nullable type.

Answer (score 0):

`where` in the class definition is a way to provide a compile-time check for any generic parameters provided to your class. It simply assures that any wrong usage stops the code from compiling rather than letting it fail at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to perform actions on your generic parameters, in some cases, the compiler need to know that this generic parameter supports those actions. the "Where" statement, tells the compiler about the type of the generic parameter.

For example in your case, you could do something like this:

```
private class Test
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}

private AB Invoke<AB>() where AB : new ()
{
    return new AB();
}
```

and the you could just use:

```
Test ResultTest = Invoke<Test>();
```

without casting anywhere. This is possible because I added "Where : new()" statement.

"Where : class" tell the that the passed parameter is a class (not a struct, a value type, an interface or some other things that are not classes).